# Cannot use GridLayout even though support lib was imported with ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, grid-layout

I have an Android project in which I am using ActionBarSherlock, which I have imported in the workspace as a separate project that also contains the Android Support Library.

I would like now to use GridLayout and I was assuming that, given the presence of the support 
library, it would be recognized and available, but it is not. Eclipse tells me that I need to set the minimum API for my project to 14, while I'm forced to leave it at 8. Is there a way I can fix this?

I hope this was clear enough. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6):

GridLayout was back ported to API 7+ only and is available as a library project in your SDK folder. You can find it at `SDK/extras/android/support/v7`.

It is not a part of ABS nor the v4 support library jar.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to identify your problem without seeing project settings.
I am able to create new project from the scratch which uses both `ActionBarSherlock` and `GridLayout` libraries.

1. Make sure you have latest `SDK`, `ActionBarSherlock`, `GridLayout`
   and `v4-support` libraries as well as an updated `ADT Eclipse
   plugin`.
2. Create new project and leave everything by-default, except for:

   ```
   Build SDK = Android 4.1 (API 16)
   Minimum Required SDK = API 8
   ```
3. Goto project Properties --> Android and add actionbarsherlock and
   gridlayout libraries.
4. Goto `res` folder and remove `values-v11` and `values-v13`
   sub-folders.
5. Edit `res\values\styles.xml`:

   ```
   <resources>
       <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light" />
   </resources>
   ```
6. Edit `res\layout\activity_main.xml`:

   ```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" >

       <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           app:columnCount="2"
           tools:context=".MainActivity" >

           <TextView
               android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
               android:text="@string/cell1"
               tools:context=".MainActivity" />

           <TextView
               android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
               android:text="@string/cell2"
               tools:context=".MainActivity" />

           <TextView
               android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
               android:text="@string/cell3"
               tools:context=".MainActivity" />

           <TextView
               android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
               android:text="@string/cell4"
               tools:context=".MainActivity" />
       </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
7. Create missing string resources (cell1,…)
8. Edit MainActivity.java:

   ```
   package com.test.gridlayout;

   import android.os.Bundle;

   import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
   import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
   import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;

   public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
           ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
           ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
           ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

           return true;
       }
   }
   ```
9. That it.

If you still have troubles, use [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/434510/GridLayoutTest.zip) demo project as starting point.

Comment: +1 for "android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout". That was just what I needed.